# How can I set GUI size of spynner python module?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4, spynner

I would like to set a particular size for [spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner) GUI, how can I do that ? (fullscreen)

I know there's [QT doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) but I don't know any `C++` and moreover I need to mix `C++` & `python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you mean in your second line, as it doesn't really have anything to do with your question...

> "...but I don't know any C++... and I need to mix C++ & python"

No C++ involved here.

If you check out the source code for spynner, and look at the Browser class, you will see that it stores the QWebView widget in an attribute: `Browser.webview`. It also says this in the docs as well.

https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner/blob/master/src/spynner/browser.py#L96

So if you want to maximize the webview window, you just need to call `showMaximized()` on it:

```
browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.debug_level = spynner.DEBUG
browser.create_webview()
browser.show()
# now maximize the webview
browser.webview.showMaximized()
```

Comment: @sputnick: No prob. Its a good thing it was designed to easily expose the underlying widgets. Sure makes it more useful that way. I haven't looked at the code much, but it would also be nice if it could optionally use an existing QApplication in case you want to integrate it with another app