# Python - Set Spynner window to specific size

Tags: python, qt, spynner

Using [spynner](/questions/tagged/spynner) in python, I'm looking for the correct approach to setting the window size to a `spynner] Webview? I've looked through the`Qt`Documentation and there does seem to be a way have a fixed size, but can't figure out how it implements in to`Python`. Any help is appreciated.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
browser = spynner.Browser()
browser.debug_level = spynner.DEBUG
browser.create_webview()
browser.show()
# now maximize the webview
browser.webview.showMaximized()
```

See [How can I set GUI size of spynner python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004973/how-can-i-set-gui-size-of-spynner-python-module)

Comment: That's for setting the window to a max, I need a specific size. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: You should try an IDE to see the completion for `browser.webview.`